# Initial conditions of a system of ODE from the numerical solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

I have a system of nonlinear differential equations of this kind:

$$f_0\left(\rho(t),\dot\rho(t),\ddot\rho(t),\phi(t),\dot\phi(t),\ddot\phi(t)\right)=0$$
$$f_1\left(\rho(t),\dot\rho(t),\ddot\rho(t),\phi(t),\dot\phi(t),\ddot\phi(t)\right)=0$$
with initial conditions:
$$\rho(0)=\rho_0,\phi(0)=\phi_0,\dot\rho(0)=\dot\rho_0,\dot\phi(0)=\dot\phi_0$$

Because is impossible to find a closed form solution, I solved it numerically. Now, I suppose to have the numerical solution. Is it possible to find the initial conditions from the set of numerical data?
Thanks

Comment: You have $ρ(t),\dot ρ(t),ϕ(t),\dot ϕ(t)$ for $t$ in some discrete set that is how far away from zero? You still have the equations of the system, only the values at $t=0$ are missing?

Comment: @LutzL: Yes. I have a set of numerical values for $t=t_k$ far away from $t=0$ and I need to have the solution for $t=0$

Comment: Then just integrate backwards. Do it from several $t_k$ and average if you want